# Fastest way to copy data from private buffer to global buffer in kernel

Tags: opencl

I have a private array of type uchar, and I would like to copy N bytes
into a global buffer of type uchar. What is the best way of doing this?

THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load up your data from private memory into a 256-bit type (like ulong4, uint8, or ushort16) and write it to 256-bit aligned addresses.

Depending on how it got to private memory and if you already have a workgroup of kernels available, an alternative would be to copy it to shared local in a single work item and then have the work group copy it to global memory using coalesced writes.

Comment: Thanks. What about endian?  My data is being stored in the private array byte by byte. I want to serialize it to global memory in the same order.

Comment: ushort16 wide; wide.s0 = upsample(byte0, byte1); wide.s1 = upsample(byte2, byte3); etc.; global[index] = wide; If byte pairs come across swapped then swap the parameters to upsample.